# Search input with virtual js keyboard doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, virtual

I am still a javascript beginner and tried to integrate the virtual keyboard into my project. This already worked without problems, unfortunately I have the problem as soon as I use an input via this keyboard in my input field type Search that the search does not work. If I enter the input directly with my keyboard the search works fine. What can be the reason for this? Also when I use the virtual keyboard to enter an input the -webkit-search-cancel-button doesn't work either or is only displayed when I move the mouse over this area.

`<input type="search" placeholder="Searchbar">`

Code example: https://codepen.io/siad/pen/jOYLJVW
Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find the error for this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @LukeVo I have adapted the code once with my problem. [link](https://codepen.io/siad/pen/jOYLJVW)